# Can't access Gmail Account

Tags: gmail

I changed my password and shortly afterward was no longer able to access my Gmail account. How can I sign into my email again?

Comment: Use your new password

Answer (score 2):

If not able to login with new password. Just change the password one more time. To change the password just use the *Forget password* link, and follow the screen instructions.

Comment: Thanks, fortunately when I went to log in again, on my computer as opposed to my phone, I was able to log in. Then I went back to my phone and received access to my email. Don't know what happened, but I have access again.